# Can somebody clarify it this is a leak?

Tags: android, memory-leaks

Please I would like to understand this situation.

If I rotate my Android application a few times and I look into the memory dump I find more than one instance of my Activity.

That looks like a leak.

But if I force garbage collection just before getting the memory dump (by pressing the button in android Studio) I find only one instance of my Activity.

I am very inclined to think I don't have a leak.

Please does anybody have a definitive answer?

[image]

Comment: If the garbage collector cleans it, then it is not a leak, although you could be more efficient by not creating waste in the first place

Comment: Android Studio's memory dump should only be dumping reachable objects (i.e., no garbage). How exactly are you doing your memory dump?

Comment: @CommonsWare Hi, by pressing the button on the profile in Android Studio, please see the image

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score -2):

Shouldn't helped you the parameters added to your Activity like:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

After that, you could handle logic of orientation changes by yourself in the [onConfigurationChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onConfigurationChanged(android.content.res.Configuration)) method.

Or the second solution (couldn't completely imagine the structure of your project) should be using the [launchMode](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#lmode) parameter in AndroidManifest.xml